# Вывод информации о процессоре

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, как получить для вывода информацию о процессоре, используемом в системе? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я, может, глупость предложу, но пока вижу только вариант с определением типа ОС, а потом вызовом соответствующих приложений самой ОС через Runtime.exec(). Для Ubuntu, например, командой приложения будет "lshw -class cpu". А потом парсить и смотреть.

Comment: Может быть, этого будет достаточно: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: Ну, если человеку именно вся информация о процессоре нужна - не хватит, нет там, как я вижу, такого ключика. А вот узнать через это тип ОС - за милую душу

Answer (score 0):

Я видел, как подобное решила Интел. У них есть утилита Intel® Intrinsics Guide, которая показывает информацию о sse/mmx командах. И она умеет показывать, какие доступны для конкретной машины, где запущена утилита. Они используют jni и для трех целевых платформ написали so/dll файлы. На сайте Интела я ее не нашел, но вот доступны все [ссылки](http://jsandber.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/intel-intrinsics-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER"));
System.out.println(System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"));
System.out.println(System.getenv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"));   
System.out.println("Available processors (cores): " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```

Comment: А этот вариант не кроссплатформенный? У меня под Ubuntu выдал:
null
null
null
Available processors (cores): 8.
Я что-то подобное видел, но это, если не ошибаюсь, обращение к виндовым параметрам.

Comment: @Yuri_Prime значит не кроссплатформенный :(